# How to check if folder is cached in Alluxio?

Tags: alluxio

How can I tell if a folder is cached or not in Alluxio? And if a folder is cached, how can I uncache it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run `bin/alluxio fs ls /path` to check the percent of data cached in Alluxio.

To free the file (or dir), run `bin/alluxio fs free /path`